# Spring secure filter to protect anonymous requests

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, spring-mvc

One more question about spring configuration...

I have several rest methods opened to everyone and not secured. These rest methods on server #1 are used by another server #2 in the same domain to get some data. The idea is that server #2 sets `my_super_secure_cookie` to some secure token and server #1 decodes and verifies it. Here is the code:

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Some code
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/public/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
    // More code
}  


public class SuperSecurityFilter extends FilterSecurityInterceptor implements Filter {
    public SuperSecurityFilter(String key) {
        super(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();

        Optional<Cookie> tokenCookie = Arrays.stream(cookies).filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals("my_super_secure_cookie")).findFirst();

        if (tokenCookie.isPresent()) {
            Cookie cookie = tokenCookie.get();
            TokenCookie.create(cookie.getValue()).validate();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Ooops!"));
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

The question is how do I configure `SecurityConfig` to use `SecurityTokenFilter` on  request to any of the `/rest/public/*` rest methods. Something like:

```
http
    .antMatcher("/rest/public/*")
    .addFilterBefore(new SuperSecurityFilter());
```

is not working, `SuperSecurityFilter` is not called on request.

p.s. I'm forced to work with this type of security model due to current business logic restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved (applied workaround?) the issue I have by implementing not filter, but interceptor, like this:

```
public class SuperSecurityInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // implementation here
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        // Nothing here
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        // Nothing here
    }
}
```

And registered this interceptor in my entity extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. Like this:

```
registry.addInterceptor(new SupeSecurityInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/rest/public/*");
```

Not sure if this is *right* thing to do though... Anyway would be glad to know about the conventional approach of implementing this type of functionality.